# Where do resource files go in a Gradle project that builds a Java 9 module?

Tags: java, gradle, embedded-resource, java-9, java-module

As of IDEA 2018.2.1, the IDE starts error-highlighting packages "not
in the module graph" from dependencies that have been modularized. I added a `module-info.java` file to my project and added the
requisite `requires` statements, but I'm now having trouble accessing
resource files in my `src/main/resources` directory.

(For a complete example, see [this GitHub project](https://github.com/chronodm/module-resource-dirs).)

When I used `./gradlew run` or `./gradlew installDist` + the resulting
wrapper script, I was able to read resource files, but when I ran my
app from the IDE, I wasn't.

I filed an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197469)
with JetBrains, and what I learned was that IDEA was using the module
path, while Gradle, by default, was using the classpath. By adding
the following block to my `build.gradle`, I was able to get Gradle
to **also** … not be able to read any resource files.

```
run {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--module', "$moduleName/$mainClassName"
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}
```

I tried `export`-ing the resource directory I was interested in as a
"package", and at compile time got a build failure with:

> error: package is empty or does not exist: mydir

Using `opens` instead of `exports` got the same error, though downgraded
to a warning.

I even tried moving the `mydir` resource directory under `src/main/java`,
but this produced the same errors / warnings, and also resulted in the
resources not being copied to the `build` directory.

Where are resources supposed to go in Java 9, and how do I access them?

---

**Note:** I've edited this question considerably after continuing to 
research the problem. In the initial question, I was also trying to
figure out how to list the files in a resource directory, but in the
course of the investigation I determined that was a red herring -- 
first, because reading resource directories only works when the
resource is being read from a `file:///` URL (and maybe not even then),
and second because plain files weren't working either, so clearly the
problem was with resource files in general and not specifically with
directories.

---

**Solution:**

Per [Slaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921521/27358), I added the following to `build.gradle`:

```
// at compile time, put resources in same directories as classes
sourceSets {
  main.output.resourcesDir = main.java.outputDir
}

// at compile time, include resources in module
compileJava {
  inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
  doFirst {
    options.compilerArgs = [
      '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
      '--patch-module', "$moduleName=" 
        + files(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs).asPath,
      '--module-version', "$moduleVersion"
    ]
    classpath = files()
  }
}

// at run time, make Gradle use the module path
run {
  inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
  doFirst {
    jvmArgs = [
      '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
      '--module', "$moduleName/$mainClassName"
    ]
    classpath = files()
  }
}
```

**Side note:** Interestingly, if I *don't* continue on to add Slaw's code that makes the `run` task execute against the JAR, attempting to read a resource directory `InputStream` in the run task now [throws an `IOException`](https://gist.github.com/chronodm/fe5788ebf0e93d84dc55e6a80472f4ef) instead of providing the list of files. (Against the JAR, it simply gets an empty `InputStream`.)

Comment: If you are making use of a named module, did you also try `--add-opens <source-module>/<package>=<target-module>`, where the package name is derived as stated in the documentation of [`Module#getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))? And by the way, what does [`--show-module-resolution`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339598/list-the-modules-resolved-during-the-application-startup) lists at the startup?

Comment: @nullpointer That's just a different way to get `package fonts not in <module-name>`, although at least the app doesn't crash. Again, this is code accessing a resource directory _in the same module_. If that requires special command-line handling, the module system is broken.

Comment: @nullpointer `--show-module-resolution` doesn't seem to show anything very interesting. it does give `root <module-name> file:///<project-dir>/out/production/classes`, which yes, does not include `out/production/resources`.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that you were able to read a folder with `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`. TIL. Not sure if this was ever a supported feature.

Comment: @DavidMoles Okay, would be good if you could share an MCVE to understand and reproduce what you're pointing out. Seems like you have only a single named(your) module and you're trying to access the resource within it. But not very clear what you're trying to achieve with the code `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fonts")`...just to add, link to github works well for me as well.

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks for the suggestion. The problem seems to be more complicated than I thought, as having created an MCVE, it behaves differently when run from my IDE, via `gradle run`, and via `java -classpath`. See https://github.com/chronodm/module-resource-dirs

Comment: *"in particular resource directories. I used to be able to read the list of files in my .. directory"* I am surprised that was ever possible when the app. was in a Jar. There are no directories in Jars, just paths that **we** might interpret as directories & that might **become** directories again after the Jar is expended. An alternate way to go is to load a `/fonts/file-list.txt` & go from there.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, the "directory InputStream = list of files" behavior appears to be undocumented, and once I can reliably load any resource whatsoever I'll probably look at adding a build step to generate the file list.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***Update (25 March 2020):** There has been significant progress towards proper JPMS support. A nightly build of Gradle 6.4 now includes options to develop with Java 9 modules natively. See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/890#issuecomment-603289940 .*

***Update (29 September 2020):** Since Gradle 6.4 (current release as of this update is 6.6.1) you can now support JPMS modules natively in Gradle projects, but you have to explicitly activate this feature:*

```kotlin
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
}
```

*See Gradle's [Java Modules Sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_java_modules_multi_project.html#header), which also links to various other pertinent documentation, for more information.*

---

## Gradle & Java 9 Module Support

Unfortunately, Gradle still—as of version 6.0.1—does not have first class support for Java 9 modules, as can be seen by the [Building Java 9 Modules](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/) guide.

> One of the most exciting features of Java 9 is its support for developing and deploying modular Java software. Gradle doesn’t have first-class support for Java 9 modules yet.
>
> Some [community plugins](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=jpms), like [java9-modularity plugin](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin), attempt to add support. This guide will be updated with more information on how to use built-in Gradle support when it is developed.

<sup>***Note:** This guide used to be more extensive and offered examples on how to customize existing tasks "manually". However, it has since changed to the above which recommends using third-party plugins that offer at least some Java 9 support. Some of these community plugins appear to offer more than just module support, such as support for using the `jlink` tool from Gradle.*</sup>

The Gradle project has an "epic" which supposedly tracks Java 9 module support: [JPMS Support #890](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/890).

---

## The Problem

The reason you can't find your resource files is because Gradle, by default, outputs the compiled classes and processed resources in different directories. It looks something like this:

```
build/
|--classes/
|--resources/
```

The `classes` directory is where the `module-info.class` file is placed. This causes a problem for the module system since technically the files under the `resources` directory are not included within the module present in the `classes` directory. This isn't a problem when using the classpath instead of the modulepath since the module system treats the whole classpath as one giant module (i.e. the so-called *unnamed module*).

If you add an `opens` directive for a resource-only package you'll get an error at runtime. The cause of the error being that the package does not exist in the module because of the aforementioned directory layout. You get a warning at compile-time for basically the same reason; the module is present in `src/main/java` and the resource files under `src/main/resources` are not technically included in that module.

<sup>***Note:** By "resource-only package" I mean packages which contain resources but none of the resources have a `.java` or `.class` extension.*</sup>

Of course, if the resources are only to be accessible to the module itself then adding the `opens` directive should not be necessary. You only need to add such directives for resource-containing packages when resources need to be accessible to other modules because resources in modules are subject to [encapsulation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

> A resource in a named module may be *encapsulated* so that it cannot be located by code in other modules. Whether a resource can be located or not is determined as follows:
>
> - If the resource name ends with "`.class`" then it is not encapsulated.
> - A *package name* is derived from the resource name. If the package name is a [package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getPackages()) in the module then the resource can only be located by the caller of this method when the package is [open](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#isOpen(java.lang.String,java.lang.Module)) to at least the caller's module. If the resource is not in a package in the module then the resource is not encapsulated.

---

## Solution

Ultimately the solution is to ensure the resources are considered part of the module. However, there are a few ways in which to do that.

### Use a Plugin

The easiest option is to use a ready-made Gradle plugin which handles everything for you. The *Building Java 9 Modules* guide gives an example of one such plugin, which I believe is currently the most comprehensive: [gradle-modules-plugin](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin).

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.javamodularity.moduleplugin") version "..."
}
```

You can also check out [other available plugins](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=jpms).

### Manually Specify Appropriate JVM Options

Another option is to configure each needed Gradle task to specify some JVM options. Since you're primarily concerned with accessing resources from within the module you need to configure the `run` task to patch the module with the resources directory. Here's an example (Kotlin DSL):

```kotlin
plugins {
    application
}

group = "..."
version = "..."

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_13
}

application {
    mainClassName = "<module-name>/<mainclass-name>"
}

tasks {
    compileJava {
        doFirst {
            options.compilerArgs = listOf(
                    "--module-path", classpath.asPath,
                    "--module-version", "${project.version}"
            )
            classpath = files()
        }
    }

    named<JavaExec>("run") {
        doFirst {
            val main by sourceSets
            jvmArgs = listOf(
                    "--module-path", classpath.asPath,
                    "--patch-module", "<module-name>=${main.output.resourcesDir}",
                    "--module", application.mainClassName
            )
            classpath = files()
        }
    }
}
```

The above uses `--patch-module` (see [`java` tool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html)):

> Overrides or augments a module with classes and resources in JAR files or directories.

If you use the example above it will get a simple Gradle project to run on the module path. Unfortunately, this gets much more complicated the more you consider:

- Test code. You have to decide if your test code will be in its own module or be patched into the main code's module (assuming you don't keep everything on the classpath for unit testing).

  - Separate module: Probably easier to configure (roughly the same configuration for `compileTestJava` and `test` as for `compileJava` and `run`); however, this only allows for "blackbox testing" due to the fact split packages are not allowed by the module system (i.e. you can only test public API).
  - Patched module: Allows for "whitebox testing" but is harder to configure. Since you won't have any `requires` directives for test dependencies you'll have to add the appropriate `--add-modules` and `--add-reads` arguments. Then you have to take into account that most testing frameworks require reflective access; since you're unlikely to have your main module as an open module you'll have to add appropriate `--add-opens` arguments as well.
- Packaging. A module can have a main class so you only have to use `--module <module-name>` instead of `--module <module-name>/<mainclass-name>`. This is done by specifying the `--main-class` option with the `jar` tool. Unfortunately, the Gradle `Jar` task class does not have a way to specify this, as far as I can tell. One option is to use `doLast` and `exec` to manually call the `jar` tool and `--update` the JAR file.
- The `application` plugin also adds tasks to create start scripts (e.g. batch file). This will have to be configured to use the modulepath instead of the classpath, assuming you need these scripts.

Basically, I highly recommend using a plugin.

### Consolidate Classes and Resources

A third option is to configure the processed resources to have the same output directory as the compiled classes.

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    main {
        output.setResourcesDir(java.outputDir)
    }
}
```

<sup>***Note:** It may be necessary to configure the `jar` task with `duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE` when setting the resources output the same as the Java output.*</sup>

I believe this may be required if you expect to `opens` resource-only packages. Even with `--patch-module` you'll get an error at runtime due to the `opens` directive since the module system appears to perform some integrity validation before applying `--patch-module`. In other words, the resource-only package won't exist "soon enough". I'm not sure if any plugin handles this use case.

At compile-time, however, it's permissible for an `opens` package to not exist, though `javac` will emit a warning. That being said, it's possible to get rid of the warning by using `--patch-module` in the `compileJava` task.

```kotlin
tasks.compileJava {
    doFirst {
        val main by sourceSets
        options.compilerArgs = listOf(
                "--module-path", classpath.asPath,
                "--patch-module", "<module-name>=${main.resources.sourceDirectories.asPath}"
                "--module-version", "${project.version}"
        )
        classpath = files()
    }
}
```

Another way to consolidate the resources and classes into the same place is to configure the `run` task to execute against the JAR file built by the `jar` task.

---

Hopefully Gradle will support Java 9 modules in a first-class manner some time soon. I believe Maven is further along in this respect.

Comment: Thanks, this clears it up considerably; and the reminder that Gradle doesn't yet have first-class module support is well taken.

Comment: Is this still valid nowadays (Gradle still doesn't have first-class support for Jigsaw modules)?

Comment: @elect As far as I can tell Gradle still doesn't have first-class support for Jigsaw modules. I added a small update somewhat near the top of my answer.

Comment: @DavidMoles [progress is (finally) being made](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/890#issuecomment-603289940)

Comment: @elect same comment

Comment: @Slaw, wonderful news, thanks a lot for the mention, really appreciated!

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

output.setResourcesDir(java.outputDir)

worked for me when my output WAR file was missing resources directory content

Answer (score 2):

Beside @Slaw's answer (thanks to him), I had to open the package that contains the resources to the caller's module. As follows (`moduleone.name module-info.java`):

```
opens io.fouad.packageone to moduletwo.name;
```

Otherwise, the following would return `null`:

```
A.class.getResource("/io/fouad/packageone/logging.properties");
```

considering that class `A` is in module `moduletwo.name` and the file `logging.properties` is inside module `moduleone.name`.

---

Alternatively, `moduleone.name` could expose a utility method that returns the resource:

```
public static URL getLoggingConfigFileAsResource()
{
    return A.class.getResource("/io/fouad/packageone/logging.properties");
}
```