# JavaFX Image from resources folder

Tags: java, javafx

For some reason I keep getting an NPE in a gradle javafx project.

My folder structure is very basic. I have a package with my java files in the `main/java` folder. I also have my resources in the `main/resources` folder. When I try to load `image.png` it gives me an NPE.

```
public static Image createImage(Object context, String url) {
    Image m = null;
    InputStream str = null;
    URL _url = context.getClass().getResource(url);

    try {
        m = new Image(_url.getPath());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return m;
}
```

This is a helper class.

From the `Scene` I call: `Image image = Helper.createImage(this, "image.png");`
The absolute path to the image would be `main/resources/images/image.png`.

I checked every tutorial on the internet but I couldn't find any solution for this. I also tried it with the path to the image as parameter and also with an `InputStream` but it never worked.

Comment: Method `getResource()` is searching for a file named _image.png_ in the package directory of `context`.

Comment: @Abra so how do I make him search in the `main/resources` dir?

Comment: Easiest solution, in my opinion, is move file _image.png_ to the same directory as your class. Have you read the _javadoc_ for method [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) ?

Comment: @Abra that is not an option. We need to place it in the resources directory

Comment: What java version are you using? Is your application packaged in a JAR?

Comment: `getResource(String)` usually searches relative to the `resources` folder. So you should try `Helper.createImage(this, "images/image.png");`. Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder) could help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Resources

The [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) and related API are used for locating resources relative to the class path and/or module path. When using `Class` to get a resource you can pass an *absolute* name or a *relative* name. An absolute name will locate the resource relative to the root of the class path/module path; an absolute name starts with a `/`. A relative name will locate the resource relative to the location of the `Class`; a relative name does not start with a leading `/`.

In a typical Maven/Gradle project structure, the `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` are *roots* of the class path/module path. This means all resource names are relative to those directories. It's slightly more complicated than that because the files under those directories are moved to the target/build directory and it's *that* location that's put on the class path/module path, but for all intents and purposes consider the source directories as the root. There's a reason a get-resource API exists in the first place, to provide an application-location-independent way of obtaining resources.

---

## Issues in Your Code

From your question I gather your project structure looks something like:

```
<project-dir>
|--src/
   |--main/
      |--java/
      |--resources/
         |--images/
            |--image.png
```

And you're calling your method with an `Object` and a resource name of `image.png`. The problem here is that, since you're passing a relative name, the resource is located relative to the `Class` of the passed `Object` (i.e. `context`). I doubt your class is located in a package named `images` which means the resource will not be found relative to said class. You need to pass an absolute name: `/images/image.png`.

The other problem is your use of `URL#getPath()`. The `URL` you obtain from `Class#getResource(String)` will, if the resource were to be found, look something like this:

```
file:/path/to/gradle/project/build/resources/main/images/image.png
```

But the result of `URL#getPath()` will give you:

```
/path/to/gradle/project/build/resources/main/images/image.png
```

This causes a problem due to the way `Image` works. From [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html):

> All URLs supported by [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html?is-external=true) can be passed to the constructor. If the passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is searched on the classpath in that case.

Notice the second sentence. If the passed URL does not have a scheme then it's interpreted as a *resource name* and the `Image` will locate the image file relative to the classpath. In other words, since you're passing the value of `URL#getPath()` to the `Image` constructor it searches for the resource `image.png` in the **package** `path.to.gradle.project.build.resources.main.images`. That package does not exist. You should be passing the URL as-is to the `Image` constructor via `URL#toString()` or `URL#toExternalForm()`.

---

## Solution

If you're going to use the `URL` returned by `Class#getResource(String)` to load the `Image` then no matter what you need to use `URL#toString()` or `URL#toExternalForm()` instead of `URL#getPath()`.

```java
public static Image createImage(Object context, String resourceName) {
  URL _url = context.getClass().getResource(resourceName);
  return new Image(_url.toExternalForm());
}
```

Then you have at least two options:

1. Pass the absolute resource name (i.e. `"/images/image.png"`) to your `#createImage(Object,String)` method since the `image.png` resource is not in the same package as the passed `Object` (i.e. `context`).
2. Move the resource to the same package as the class of the passed in `Object` (i.e. `context`). For instance, if the context object's class is `com.foo.MyObject` then place the resource under `src/main/resources/com/foo` and it will be in the same package as `MyObject`. This will allow you to continue passing the relative resource name.

Of course, as noted by the documentation of `Image` you can pass a scheme-less URL and it's interpreted as a resource name. In other words, you could do:

```java
Image image = new Image("images/image.png");
```

And that should work. A note of caution, however: When using modules the above will only work if the resource-containing package is `opens` *unconditionally* or if the module itself is `open`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I am using in fact a `module`. Right now I am opening some parts of the application to javafx.controls. But how would I write it so that it is open to grab resources? Unfortunately above answer gives an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: For above comment: We don't want to open up the complete module if possible because we only want the database package to open up to our JDBC dependency. But it is also not convenient to put assets only in the package level because some assets might be used in different packages.

Comment: In regards to resources, you only have to worry about `opens` directives if the resource is [encapsulated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). If you don't want to `opens` the resource's package then the best option is to pass the full, valid URL to the `Image` constructor as that will "bypass" the resource-locating mechanism and access the resource directly via the `URL`. The same goes for other JavaFX APIs that accept resource names, such as `[Scene|Parent]#getStylesheets()`.

Comment: Personally, I recommend the full, valid URL approach when using modules. This is especially true when using Gradle since that tool, by default, [has issues with Java modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921521/6395627).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the path `/images/image.png`.

The resources always get referenced from the class root, in your case src/main/resources, so from there going to /images/image.png should be the correct path.

Comment: If the answer works for you, pls remember to flag the answer as correct ;)

Comment: Should work. `Class.getResource("/...")` uses an absolute path (from the class path), whereas without preceding `/`  it is a relative path to the actual class' package path. `x.y.z.C.class.getResoure("u/v/w.png")` would use `/x/y/z/u/v/w.png`.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I am passing the images in my application. ivSerialAssignmentLogo is a FXML element (ImageView).

`ivSerialAssignmentLogo.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/serialAssignment.svg")));`

In your case, you could use something like that

```
public static Image createImage(Object context, String url) {
    Image m = null;
    InputStream str = null;
    URL _url = context.getClass().getResource("/images/" + url);

    try {
        m = new Image(_url.getPath());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return m;
}
```