# Loading resource file from external module using Class

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty trying to load a resource file from an external module's resource folder. I am using IntelliJ and our project is built using Maven.

The original code, prior to using modules was as such:

`getClass().getResourceAsStream(rulesFile)`

This now results in a `null` result.

---

The structure of the modules is as such:

```
client
    - java
        - org.example.client
            - Controller.java

data
    - java
        - ...
    - resources
        - org.example.data.files
            - rulesFile
```

In module `client`:

`getClass().getResourceAsStream(rulesFile)` does not work.

However, if I try and do `ModuleLayer.boot().findModule("data").get().getResourceAsStream(rulesFile)`, then it works fine.

My question is, is it possible to make the `rulesFile` visible to the `Controller.java` inside the `client` module so that a normal class loader can be used? I would like to avoid having to explicitly specify the module name it is coming from as similar code to load files from the `data` module is used elsewhere.

What options do I have to avoid having to explicitly giving the module name?

I have tried adding the following to the `data` module file, with no success:

`opens org.example.data.files to client`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861589/accessing-resource-files-from-external-modules

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I looked over that before but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources

add in your client module pom.xml:

```
<project>
    ...

    <build>
    ...

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>../data/src/main/resources/org/example/data/files</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>rulesFile</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Thanks for sharing - however, I'd like to avoid having to specify the paths of the files explicitly to the packages, else I could just get them from the model.

Comment: You could just have directory pointing to resources
<directory>../data/src/main/resources/</directory>

Comment: That’s true, a possible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the modules is as such:

```
client
    - java
        - org.example.client
            - Controller.java

data
    - java
        - Data.java
    - resources
        - org.example.data.files
            - rulesFile
```

For now, maybe not the most ideal solution, but it seems that you can load from the `data` module when working from a `Class` inside the `data` module.

It is also important to note I have opened the `data` resources folder to the `client` module as well.

Rather than trying something like:

`Controller.class.getResourceAsStream(rulesFile)`

If you do:

`Data.class.getResourceAsStream(rulesFile)` it works, this is because `Data.java` is inside the `data` module, where the `rulesFile` resides.

Answer (score 0):

In a Java `.ear` type package artifact, this also happens where you need the classpath of one module to include another module.  In that case, marking the necessary module as a dependency in the "wanting" module should incorporate it into the classpath of the
"wanter".  Specifically, this occurs with `wars` needing to access `ejbs` in an `ear`.

You would add the module simply by artifact name to the dependency section of the "wanting" module's `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <artifactId>data</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies
```

The other attributes of the artifact are inferred by your parent pom in Maven so you don't need to mention `version`, or `groupId`.  Scope could be cited as `runtime` but I think that may be default anyway.

If all goes well, you should be able to just do `getClass().getResourceAsStream(rulesFile)`.

Comment: The client module does have a dependency on the data module. Before our switch to Java 11, this did the trick and the class path didn’t matter for loading of the resources. However, it doesn’t seem to work now with the module setup.